# C - socket programming client server - connection on host name

Tags: c, sockets

On my server I have this code at the moment:

```
      #define h_addr h_addr_list[0]

      serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

      /* Set IP address to localhost */
      hostname[1023] = "\0";
      gethostname(hostname, 1023);
      printf("HostName: %s\n", hostname); // this one prints correctly

      my_hostent = gethostbyname(hostname);
      printf("Host: %s\n", my_hostent->h_addr);
      printf("IP: %c\n", inet_ntoa(my_hostent->h_addr));
      serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *hostname;
```

And on client side, I have it that you must write the host as parameter so I could write -h www.abc.com in this example I let myself say that my server hosts on www.abc.com also, but they never communicate at the moment, but when I print the hostname it says the same.

client code.

```
#define h_addr h_addr_list[0]

struct hostent *server;

server = gethostbyname(hostname);
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = server->h_addr;
```

the "hostname" variable is the parameter from program start.

this is client error:

```
 warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
   serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = server->h_addr;
```

this is server errors:

```
server.c:42:18: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
   hostname[1023] = "\0";
                  ^
server.c:43:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gethostname’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   gethostname(hostname, 1023);
   ^
server.c:48:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘inet_ntoa’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   printf("IP: %c\n", inet_ntoa(lol->h_addr));
   ^
```

Can anyone see what my failure is with sockets and connecting them together?

At the moment if I set both sides to INADDR_ANY it will work and automatically connect,

Comment: Also tried doing:

serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = lol->h_addr;

but it says I'm making integer from pointer without cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr` is a `uint32_t` and `server->h_addr` is a `char *`.

The `h_addr` field is actually an alias for `h_addr_list[0]`, where `h_addr_list` is a `char **`.  This field points to an array of address structures, which can be either `struct in_addr` or `struct in6_addr`.

In the case of `gethostbyname`, it will be a `struct in_addr`, so you need to cast it to that and assign it to `serverAddr.sin_addr` instead of `serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr`:

```
serverAddr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)server->h_addr);
```

This is not a valid declaration:

```
hostname[1023] = "\0";
```

What you want is this:

```
char hostname[1023] = {0};
```

This will initialize the whole array to zeros.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> server.c:42:18: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
>    hostname[1023] = "\0";
>                   ^
> ```

The `"\0"` is a string literal representing an array of two `const char`s, both zero.  In your assignment statement, as in most other contexts, the expression is converted to a pointer to the first char.  Evidently, `hostname` is a `char` array or `char *`, so that `hostname[1023]` is an lvalue representing a single `char`.  You are trying to assign a char pointer to that char.

You want a char literal instead:

```
hostname[1023] = '\0';
```

or, equivalently, just

```
hostname[1023] = 0;
```

> ```
> server.c:43:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gethostname’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>    gethostname(hostname, 1023);
>    ^
> server.c:48:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘inet_ntoa’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>    printf("IP: %c\n", inet_ntoa(lol->h_addr));
>    ^
> ```

You have failed to `#include` the headers declaring functions `gethostname()` and `inet_ntoa()`.  On a POSIX system, those would be

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```